# This is a React js Interview Question which was asked to me and I would want to know the answer for this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, frontend, backend

We have an appointment booking React JS application. Now, if there comes a scenario where 2 users book the appointment on the same slot simultaneously at the exact same time, how will or how should the backend know which request it should process first?

Comment: The key words are "book the appointment" (what legal force does that imply?) and "at the exact same time" (how would this look to the server?).

Comment: Normally the backend will just start processing what comes in first. At the exact moment is very very unlikely because there will always be a difference, even if it is a 100 of a millisecond. 

But it can be the backend has a queu and waits a certain period of time (for example 10 milliseconds) and then processes the one that has the lowest transaction id

Answer (score 0):

This is not the responsibility of the backend . It's the responsability of  the **server** who runnnig your backend . And the way it handles two requests ( `in your example 2 users book the appointment on the same slot simultaneously at the exact same time`)  is when they arrive to the **`CNI`** in the server it has like a memory buffer  one will be serviced at once, and the other will remain in memory until the CPU gets around to handling it